# How to set the maximum number of redirects for urllib2.urlopen in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to allow maximum of 3 redirects for `urllib2.urlopen()`. How do I specify that in `urllib2.urlopen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your own [`HTTPRedirectHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler) which counts the number of redirects and then [install it to be used by urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.install_opener).